# Older sister is taken and replaced with a mud golem

Tags: story-identification, books

The book was about an older sister that gets taken and replaced by what I think was a mud golem of some sorts, possibly as a result of magic. In case someone wanted to check it out, I highly recommend it!

The "girl" looks just like the original and wakes up by a lake without any memory of what happened and crawls covered in dirt through her bedroom window.  At morning the younger sister seems untrusting to her "older sister" because she actually saw these kidnappers place the mud doll of her sister at the lake.

The doll discovered she wasn't really who she was made to appear to be and the younger sister starts to warm to the doll and they go on an adventure to try to find the real sister.

The girl at some point also starts to like drop leaves, web, and mud off her body I think?

It took place in an 'old timey' kind of setting.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: It was in the school library and I think the Year was maybe 2017/2018 I remember what seemed like a foggy lake maybe as the cover and it was a physical copy.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise about what you mean by an 'old timey' setting? Are we talking a hundred years or more like a thousand?

Comment: 1884 some where around that time period.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that if there was a golem, magic was involved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's quite possible this is [*Cuckoo's Song*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1712838) (2014) by Frances Hardinge.  It's set a bit later than your guess - just after WWI instead of at the end of the 19th century - but relatively close.

The protagonist is Not-Triss, who is a changeling left by the Architect's underlings when they took Triss.  Not-Triss is made of sticks and leaves and things, and starts to fall apart as she approaches the end of her seven-day lifespan.

Quoting from the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_Song_(novel)):

> Triss has been unwell since being rescued from The Grimmer, a pond near their holiday cottage in Lower Bentling. Her memory is hazy. She sees her dolls coming alive. She has a gargantuan appetite, and feels an urge to eat her possessions as well as food. **She finds dead leaves in her hair, and her tears are spiderweb.** [...]
>
> Triss follows Pen to a meeting with the Architect. Pen admits she led Triss to the Grimmer to be abducted. **The Besiders threw a stick doll containing some of Triss's possessions into the Grimmer, which emerged as a changeling with Triss's appearance and some of her memories**. Learning she is not the real Triss, she now identifies herself as Not-Triss.
>
> [...]
>
> **Not-Triss now seeks to locate and rescue the real Triss from the Architect**. She also wants to release Sebastian's soul, and prolong Not-Triss's own life beyond its seven-day design.

Unfortunately I can't find a [cover](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?1712838) that matches your memory.

Comment: Thank you thank you its exactly that!!!! Sorry my memory is not great and I get confused with descriptions!

Comment: Foggy lake covers? [This](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1501754989i/35904817.jpg) or perhaps [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/S/compressed.photo.goodreads.com/books/1543008407i/42938629.jpg)

Comment: I have awful memory I might have been mistaking another book